# PIL and opencv display different image background from same image

Tags: opencv, python-imaging-library

I have images as bellow:

[image: original images]
I try to plot them on google colab.
By using PIL:

```
    from PIL import Image
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    img = Image.open('hiclipart.com(1).png')
    plt.imshow(img)
```

and by using opencv:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("hiclipart.com(1).png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
plt.imshow(img)
```

but opencv gave me images with a black background, and PIL gave white background.
What is the matter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you opened the image with **OpenCV**, you didn't specify any flags which means you get 3-channel, 8-bit BGR.

However, your image has a fourth, alpha channel which you discard unless you use:

```
img = cv2.imread("path", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```